# How to check for null after a node result-set has been returned in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

for instance :

```
<xsl:variable name="testing" select="node/nodeset/nodevalueresult"/>
```

How do i check wither of the variable or the `node/nodeset/nodevalueresult` and handle if a null is returned using either count function or any other option.

Comment: What do you consider a "null" value when you select a node-set or a sequence (as you have tagged the question as [tag:xslt-2.0]) of nodes? An empty node-set or an empty sequence?

Comment: @MartinHonnen  I would consider it to be an empty node-set in this context

Comment: There's no such thing as null in the XPath data model. The expression returns an empty sequence. You can test whether a sequence is empty using `empty(x)`, or `count(x)=0`, or you can just take the effective boolean value: `if (x) then ... else ...`.

Comment: @MichaelKay does that mean that count("select="node/nodeset/nodevalueresult)=0" ) will check for if null or empty?

Comment: As I said, (a) there's no such thing as null, and (b) `count(xx)=0` tests whether xx is empty.

Comment: @Martin Honnen  and Michael Kay thanks guys. I tested it now and its working.

Answer (score 0):

Bookmark any XPath (as XPath is the expression language used by XSLT) function reference like http://maxtoroq.github.io/xpath-ref/ and look for something doing the job like http://maxtoroq.github.io/xpath-ref/fn/empty.html e.g. `empty($testing)`.